# Omnet++,Veins,Sumo - How to get CO2 emission data for a number of vehicle as a whole?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

When using omnet++ to get CO2 emission, the data is given for each node(vehicle) seperately. Is there a way to take the data for a number of vehicles or for the whole simulation as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

The functions you are looking for are covered in section 12 "Result Recording and Analysis" of the OMNeT++ manual https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:ana-sim. It explains how you can merge multiple results into one.